# Initialize multiple google map locations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

For some reason, the `var mapLocation_1` does not load. I only see the background-color.

```
function initialize() {

    //bgMap
    var bgMap = new google.maps.LatLng(24.4887956, 54.3505189);
    var mapOption_bgMap = {
        center: bgMap,
        zoom: 15,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapOption_bgMap); // bgMap
    var load_marker_bgMap = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: bgMap,
        icon: '_/images/marker-icon.png'
    });

    load_marker_bgMap .setMap(map);
    /* </bgmp> */

    //bgMap
    var mapLocation_1 = new google.maps.LatLng(29.125285,-82.048823);
    var mapOption_mapLocation_1 = {
        center: mapLocation_1,
        zoom: 15,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapLocation_1"), mapOption_mapLocation_1); // bgMap
    var load_marker_mapLocation_1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: mapLocation_1,
        icon: '_/images/marker-icon.png'
    });
    load_marker_mapLocation_1.setMap(map);
    /* </bgmp> */
} //initialiseMap

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a[data-toggle='tab']").on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    initialize();
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!